# Is there a function on java 8 API to count days between two dates (both inclusive)?

Tags: java, date, java-8, count

The signature of `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between method` is:

> public long between(Temporal temporal1Inclusive,
>                       Temporal temporal2Exclusive)

So the last date is not included as it relates the example:

```
LocalDate from = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate to = from.plusDays(1);

ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to); // Result is 1
```

**Is there another function to get 2 days in that expression?**

Otherwise I only see that I could do that as the following:

```
LocalDate from = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate to = from.plusDays(1);

ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to.plusDays(1)); // Result is 2
```

Comment: What's wrong with `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to) + 1`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually NO, but you can use the following code:

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to) + 1;
```

`+1` adds 1 day to the difference between those two local dates so we can say that the last date is included.

Comment: Yeah, It looks the obvious way of doing. I just wanted to know why they (java api) implemented only with excluded end date. Holidays are inclusive, maternity leaves are inclusive, only if you spend nights at hotel the last day will be exclusive, isn't it?.

Comment: Because it is easier to write `+1` than introducing a method like `betweenEndIncluded(...)`.

Comment: I agree with @Flown because it is easier to use +1 than using a method. But temporal1 inclusive and temporal2 Exclusive is used since JDK1.0

Comment: @Joe - Upper bounds are conventionally exclusive in many zero-based languages, including Java.  (`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` and all that...)

Comment: So the answer would be no, isn't it?, but we could use it as ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to) + 1;